# C# - Machine has 250 ips, I can only retrieve 50 from code

Tags: c#, networking

I have a linux (ubuntu server 14.04) machine with 250 ips. When I run my c# code in mono, it only retrieves 50 ips.

All ips are configured correctly, I have the same code in java, and all 250 ips are found, and can be bound to.

I have tried:

```
Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList;
```

and

```
Dns.GetHostAddresses(string.Empty);
```

both return 50 ips?

So, my question, is there a limit in c# on how many ips can be discovered? or any other reason anyone knows of why this would be happening?

Comment: Have you tried with native Windows and .Net, instead of Mono on Linux?

Comment: unfortunately I cannot as it is an ubuntu server machine..

Comment: Then I think you should add Mono as a tag for your question, since it is unknown if this is a .Net problem as such.

Comment: True, I was in two minds, as I wanted to open it up a bit to see if anyone had done the same on a windows machine and retrieved more than 50, then I would know it is not .net..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend switching to a different method to obtain the same data.

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

What you are asking the code to do is to take the current machine, and ask a second server what all IP addresses are registered. Instead it would be easier, and more reliable, to ask the server you are on what the IP addresses are. Some may not be registered to a DNS server, either local, or remote.

Answer (score 0):

Josh's answer is correct, but for completeness, here is the complete code to get the IPs:

```
var interfaces =  System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

foreach (var netInterface in interfaces)
{
     IPInterfaceProperties ipProps = netInterface.GetIPProperties();

     foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation addr in ipProps.UnicastAddresses)
     {
           Console.WriteLine(addr.Address.ToString());
     }                 
}
```